# Deleting an android ListView row on LongClick

Tags: android, listview, swipe, delete-row

I have this code to get data from database and display in a ListView

```
List<Contact> contacts = db2.getAllContacts();
        ArrayList<String> MY_LIST = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Contact cn : contacts) {
            String outputt = "Id: " + cn.getID() + ", Message: " + cn.getMessage() +
                    ", Time: " + cn.getDate();
            MY_LIST.add(outputt);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MY_LIST);


        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I want to delete a particular item/row on the ListView on swipe. 
How can I achieve that ?

Comment: I also provided a good github link and got two dislikes.! wow so bias , tat these two guys also gave reference to other links and didnt get any dislike.!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I spent one full day studying and learning. I did it this way.

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                           int pos, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.v("long clicked", "pos: " + pos);

                MY_LIST.remove(pos); //where pos is position of item I click
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why did you down-vote my answer ? I did study and just posted a useful solution which is simple and works perfectly fine. Are you not in favour of people doing research to find a solution to their problems ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EnhancedListView](https://github.com/timroes/EnhancedListView). Just copy the the `EnhancedListView` class from the linked repo in your project. Then instead of `ListView`, use and `EnhancedListView` in your code. I.e.:

```
EnhancedListView listView = (EnhancedListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

// Then set an EnhancedListView.OnDismissCallback:

listView.setDismissCallback(new de.timroes.android.listview.EnhancedListView.OnDismissCallback() {

            @Override
            public EnhancedListView.Undoable onDismiss(EnhancedListView listView, final int position) {

                final String item = (String) adapter.getItem(position);
                adapter.remove(position);
                // If you'd like the user to be able to undo a swipe:
                return new EnhancedListView.Undoable() {
                    @Override
                    public void undo() {
                        adapter.insert(position, item);
                    }
                };
            }
        });

// Enable swipe to dismiss:

listView.enableSwipeToDismiss();
```

Note: The repo is not maintained by the developer anymore in favour of the new `RecyclerView` by Google. But you can easily use it by just copying the `EnhancedListView` class in your code.

Comment: Upvoted. Thanks a lot. This thing is depricated. But your answer did let me to discover android's recyclerview which looks great and I should study it. I studied a bit further and managed to get my work done.

Comment: That's great. You can post your solution as the answer so that other's may benefit.

Comment: Yes, I have just posted my answer below and someone down-voted it.

Comment: If downvoter (on this answer) could please explain the reason I would be able to answer better in the future.